# UnhandledPromiseRejection error in React test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am doing test on the React+Typescript using React Testing Library and Jest. This test could not run at all with the following error:

> [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing
> inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
> promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with
> the reason "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'json')".] {   code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION' }

Here is my test. Please help my to fix it.

```
const renderComponent = (): RenderResult => {
  return render(
      <List />,
    {}
  );
};

const { getByTestId, findByTestId, findByText } = screen;

const renderElements = (): any => {
  const component = renderComponent();
  return {
    deleteIcon: screen.getByTestId("delete-icon"),
    dialogPopup: screen.getByTestId("dialog-popup"),
    component,
  };
};

describe("When click on Delete icon", () => {
  it("should show Dialog Confirmation Popup", () => {
    const { deleteIcon, dialogPopup } = renderElements();
    userEvent.click(deleteIcon);
    expect(dialogPopup).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: Not seeing this `(reading 'json')` anywhere in your code, so it looks like we need more details.

Comment: My guess is that you are calling `fetch` somewhere in your code get the response with `response.json()`. You might mock `fetch` but return the wrong object.

Comment: Show the code of the component.